# NSMutable array count not changing after removed child

Tags: objective-c, cocos2d-iphone

```
GMSprite *bulletMove;
int bulletCount = [bullets count];

for(int i = 0; i < bulletCount; i++)
{        
    if(bulletMove.position.x > 500)
    {
        [self removeChild:[bullets objectAtIndex:i] cleanup:YES];
    }
}
```

How do i remove the child from the array and also the object in the array so that bulletCount goes down an integer and adjusts the array to the removed object

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use below code:

```
[bullets removeObjectAtIndex:i];
```

Get bullet object from bulet array and use below code.

```
[bullet removeFromParentAndCleanup:YES];
```

Comment: when i use this, the sprite still stays on the screen, does this take up memory, how do i remove the sprite image/
what i did was i created a temp of the array object, then removed the array object then self removechilded the temp object, do you think this method is okay?

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
[bullets removeObjectAtIndex:i];
```

> How do i remove the child from the array and also the object in the
>   array so that bulletCount goes down an integer and adjusts the array
>   to the removed object

Using the above method will remove the object from index i and all following objects will shift one-up.

Comment: That's why it's easier to use `for (int i = bulletCount - 1; i >= 0; i--)` to avoid problems with index shifting.

Comment: when i use this, the sprite still stays on the screen, does this take up memory, how do i remove the sprite image

Comment: what i did was i created a temp of the array object, then removed the array object then self removechilded the temp object, do you think this method is okay?

Comment: @user2121776: you revmoved from self, not from bullets. And i guess you asked how to remvove and make one less in size of bullets and shift all towards begining of array.

Answer (score 0):

```
GMSprite *bulletMove;


for(int i = 0; i < [bullets count]; )
{        
    if(bulletMove.position.x > 500)
    {
        [bullets removeObjectAtIndex:i];
    } else {
        i++;
    }
}
```

It is not exactly good style manipulating the index varialbe of a for loop within its body. You may want to re-structure this suggestions with antother type of loop (do-while or so). The basic idea is, however, that [bullest count] will always provide you with the current amount of entries in the array. And the index must only be increased if you do not remove the current object. If you remove it an your index is at 10 (example) then the next one to be checkt is at 10 again. If you remove that too then the next one to be checked against the 500 is agein at 10. So either remove it or increase the index. And as exit criteria of the loop check the index against the *current* amount of objects in the array.

Edit: Second part of your question: If you do your memory management right, regardless wether you ARC or not, removeObjectAtIndex should properly remove the object itself. (Unless its retain count was higher than 1 or another strong reference still exists. But even then it reduces the retain count by 1 and does exactly the right thing.)